# Twitter Bootstrap: open nav-tabs using script from php

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to open a nav-tabs using script from a php file(*the php file is external*). I tried using this one `echo "<script>alert('success')open('colors.php#yellow','_self')</script>";` to direct to the page where it will open a nav-tab with an ID of yellow

i have this **HTML**

```
<div class="container">

<!-------->
<div id="content">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Red</a></li>
        <li><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Orange</a></li>
        <li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">Yellow</a></li>
        <li><a href="#green" data-toggle="tab">Green</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blue" data-toggle="tab">Blue</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="red">
            <h1>Red</h1>
            <p>red red red red red red</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="orange">
            <h1>Orange</h1>
            <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
            <h1>Yellow</h1>
            <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="green">
            <h1>Green</h1>
            <p>green green green green green</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="blue">
            <h1>Blue</h1>
            <p>blue blue blue blue blue</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PHP** open_color.php

```
echo "<script>alert('success')open('colors.php#yellow','_self')</script>"
```

my output is still the red tab will be opened as active

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

**open_color.php:**

```
$val = $_REQUEST['some_var'];

    switch ($val) {
        case 'red':
            header("Location: colors.php#red");
            break;

        . . .

        default:
            header("Location: colors.php");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer sir but not its not working even the `Location` code